# How to get id and state attibutes in LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to learn C# (and Linq-to-Xml) for handling of XML files, yet having some troubles.

I can get the elements and values, but my output is missing the information I need for logic decisions (**id** and **state** attributes in the transaction and target elements).

I think it has to do with the Descendants, but not sure how to grab them.

A little nudge in the right direction?

**My XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2">
    <file source-language="en-US" datatype="plaintext" category="framework">
        <body>
            <transaction approved="no" id="1">
                <source xml:lang="en-US">Product Family</source>
                <target state="translated" xml:lang="en-US">Product Family</target>
            </transaction>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

**C# Code**

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Show the dialog, using defaults, and get result
    OpenFileDialog ofdResult = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (ofdResult.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        try
        {
           if (ofdResult.OpenFile() != null)
           {
               XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(ofdResult.FileName);
               // print elements recursively
               PrintElement(xmlFile.Root);
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk." + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

// display an element (and its children, if any) in the TextBox
private void PrintElement( XElement element )
{
    // get element name without namespace
    string name = element.Name.LocalName;

    // display the element's name within its tag
    tbxOutput.AppendText( '<' + name + ">\n" ); 

    // check for child elements and print value if none contained
    if ( element.HasElements )
    {
        // print all child elements at the next indentation level
        foreach ( var child in element.Elements() )

            // Display all attributes
            PrintElement(child);

    } // end if
    else
    {
        // display the text inside this element 
        tbxOutput.AppendText( element.Value.Trim() + '\n' );
    } // end else

    // display end tag
    tbxOutput.AppendText( "</" + name + ">\n" );
} // end method PrintElement
```

**My Output...**

```
<xliff>
<file>
<body>
<trans-unit>
<source>
Product Family
</source>
<target>
Product Family
</target>
</trans-unit>
</body>
</file>
</xliff>
```

Comment: You do realize that `XDocument.ToString()` will print out all of the XML, right? :)

Comment: Why don't you just use `xmlFile.ToString()`?!

Comment: Hey, I said I was trying to learn  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need attributes why don't you read attributes? XElement has a boolean property HasAttributes and you can loop over all attributes in the same way like you do it for Elements(). Use Attributes() method for that. Please refer to the MSDN article [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can write a method like

```
    string GetAttributesString(XElement element)
    {
        if(element == null || !element.HasAttributes)
            return string.Empty;

        string format = " {0}={1}";
        StringBuider result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var attribute in element.Attributes())
        {
            result.AppendFormat(format, attribute.Name, attribute.Value);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

And use it in your PrintElement method

```
    tbxOutput.AppendText("<" + name + GetAttributesString(element) + ">\n");
```

Comment: Okay.....  the {0} refers to the ID  and the {1} = the value assigned to ID.   How would I access that to compare against it?  In the LINQ command on a SELECT?   ANy good book to recommend?

Comment: Added code and worked good for all attributes of an element.  I just need the id (attribute.Name="id") on the transaction element... And on target element I want only the state (attribute.Name="state") value  .... Need to my have my xnl records loaded input based on the code those values and how I process them.

Comment: You can modify the code to something like that foreach(var attribute in element.Attributes().Where(a => (element.Name.LocalName == "transaction" && a.Name == "id") || (element.Name.LocalName == "target" && a.Name == "state")))

Comment: Now a theory question...  Obviously, transaction and /transaction are a logical unit...  So, to be able to edit various transactions based on my filters, would I have a method to load all trans/source/target records and THEN check the filters, before adding them to my working data area?  Make sense?

Comment: You are right. <transaction>...</transaction> is a one XElement. since you already loaded all XDocument in memory then all it's child elements are already loaded. You just need to pass appropriate XElement to the method you mentioned (e.g. XElement DoEdit(XElement element)) and all children (source and target) of the selected transaction will be accessible inside that method.

Comment: want to help me wrtite the tool I amn doing for my customer? hehehehe

Comment: lol) we can discuss it. pls email me semenov.vasily@gmail.com